# Как запомнить Http авторизацию?

Tags: c#, .net, http

Создаю `HttpWebRequest`, работаю при этом с `CredentialCache` для авторизации. В пределах одной сессии это помогает, но после перезапуска приложения, само собой, приходится авторизоваться заново. `CredentialCache` не сериализуемый класс. Как его сохранить? Или может есть встроенные методы для хранения паролей (насколько мне известно в винде есть диспетчер хранения учетных данных, но как им воспользоваться)? Просто я работаю с `SecureString`, и если я просто буду хранить пароль в файле как есть, то вся безопасность накрывается медным тазом.

Comment: Но разве вам реально нужен пароль открытым текстом? Ведь передавать пароль каждый раз по сети как-то неправильно.

Comment: @VladD, а как иначе? Это http basic авторизация.

Comment: А, ну если так, то да. Ну может быть для этого случая перейти на что-то более продвинутое? Хранение, а особенно передача по сети plaintext-паролей — это как-то очень нехорошо.

Comment: @VladD, нужный мне сервис работает именно по http basic и никак иначе. Как там это передается, меня мало заботит, мне важно, чтобы дыр не было именно в моем приложении.